# calling the same function in an object oriented way

Tags: function, oop, lua

Standard lua allows me to call functions with variables. e.g. see code below:

```
function person(func) --func value: saySomething
    local thefunc = func
    thefunc() --var used to call function works
end

function saySomething()
    print("hello")
end
```

So my question is can we do the same in an object oriented way? e.g.:

```
--psuedo code to give you a general idea
class test
function test:init(func) --func value: saySomething
    self.func = func
end

function test:person()
    self:self.func() --this doesnt work
end

function test:saySomething()
    print("hello")
end
```

Comment: you can jus do `self:func()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
self[self.func](self) --self.func needs to be a string for it to work
```

Comment: you can use `self.func = test.saySomething` and do `self:func()` later to call the method `saySomething` on `self`, no need for storing keys to functions.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a function in a table with `:` as separator sets the first given parameter on call as local variable `self` to the function body.

Calling a function in a table with `:` as separator adds the table reference as first argument to the parameters list.

```
local myclass = {}

function myclass:saySomething()
    print(self)
end
myclass.saySomething("Jiiiiiii~")   -- Jiiiiiii~

function myclass.saySomething(self)
    print(self)
end
myclass:saySomething()  -- table: 0x000a6ea0
```

As you see it's intended to use this form of call & function together for OO in Lua.

To go further, you should take a look on [metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4).

When you want private members, you can hide these variables in the object construction function, see [closures](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.5).